# ATI Radeon HD 5770 Cooling

Tags: graphics-card, cooling, amd-radeon

I have a Radeon HD 5770 manufactured by ATI. In the course of using compressed air to clean it the fan shattered. I put a case fan on the card to cool it, but it's not doing a great job; the temperature goes to nearly 100 sometimes. The card is not overclocked or anything, the PC itself is clean.

I looked around for a third party cooling system but the only one I found was the [Accelero L2 Pro](http://www.arctic.ac/en/p/cooling/vga/23/accelero-l2-pro.html?c=2182). It's low on stock and I don't know how great it will be, some review say it may not fit on all 5770 cards.

Does anyone know of another one that will work? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check newegg. They seem to have a ton. Just make sure there aren't any compatibility issues: http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=gpu+cooler&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 0):

The Arctic Cooling cooler should fit as it says this on the site:

> ATI Radeon HD 5870, 5850, 5770, 5750

Stock coolers are never that good. They only cool it as much as it's needed mainly to save costs.

Arctic Cooling are very good coolers. I've fitted two separate ones on cards I've owned in the past and the temperatures have always been about 20-30 degrees cooler than the stock cooler. So, personally, I'd get that cooler and fit it :)

P.S. Oh and compressed air is crap. Best thing to use is a dry paintbrush and a standard hoover. Just make sure the fans dont spin when you're cleaning it as it can send a charge back into the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have fitted the Accelero L2 Pro to the ASUS EAH5770 CUCore/2DI/1GD5 (HD 5770) it works great and keeps the card a lot cooler around 50 degrees C while gaming and the GPU clocked at 930 MHz.

To get the cooler to fit snugly I didn't use the supplied spacers and reused the stock spring loaded screws.

Answer (score 0):

There are two typical styles of gpu fans on modern video cards such as the 5770

-Ducted
-Bladed

---

**Ducted Fan**

[image: ducted fan]

---

**Bladed Fan**

[image: bladed fan]

ATI ducted fans are all the same size

Bladed fans come in many sizes

- 75 mm x 40 mm [Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BA08YWA)
- 70 mm x 10 mm [Example](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835119132)
- 65 mm

Your 5770 is most likely a ducted fan. I won't link to exactly which one you should buy, but if you search google shopping for `ati 5770 gpu fan` you should find lots of ducted fans on ebay for less than $25

If you are willing to spend a little more money, zalman makes some high performance gpu fans.

http://www.zalman.co.kr/eng/product/CategorySecond_Pic.php